# Could I use GIT in a situation where each file is essentially its own repo

Tags: git

**NOTE:** Even though (from the discussions that have already taken place) it looks like GIT is in fact not a good fit for this use case, I have opened this question up to a bounty to prompt a more definitive answer, hopefully from someone who has a good deal of experience with GIT. The original question is below.

I have a situation where I have a large collection of files that are independent. By independent I mean that each file doesn't depend on the presence, absence or particular state of the files around it. A good analogy would be a directory of images, where our workflow allows each image to be created, edited and removed independently, and work done on an image has no bearing on the other images in the directory.

Note that this independence is not just incidental, but is critical to our workflow.

Each of these files would benefit from a GIT like work flow. It would be nice to be able to track the changes to each file, have people work on each file in independent branches and then merge their changes when done (so, for the sake of our analogy, imagine these are SVG images, where you might have an artist drawing the image and a translator translating the text content), and access the files from other projects that use GIT.

From my experience, GIT is great when you have a collection of files that are all in a particular state. For example, when you commit a GIT repo after reaching the state of "Production Release 1.2", every file then shares the state of "Production Release 1.2" at that commit.

But I'm not sure how to apply the GIT workflow, or if it is even practical to do so, when each file does not and can not share the state of the files around it. You could place each file in its own GIT repo, but that doesn't seem practical.

So, my questions are:

1. Is my impression that GIT only works on a collection of related files correct?
2. If not, what would be the process for using GIT's clone/branch/merge functionality on a file by file basis?

UPDATE

In response to iberbeu: it's not that I see versions as being X.Y, it's that I see GIT commits as assuming all files in a repo have the same version or commit point (however you define a version). In which case the files in a GIT repo are not totally independent.

The issue here is when you take a single repo with all the independent files, clone it into your own local repo and starting working on a branch. At this point all the files are assumed to belong to the branch, even though from the point of view of the work flow we have, you are only working on one single file. However, now all these independent files are "along for the ride", taking on the revision history associated with the single file that you actually want to edit.

So Joe might create a branch of a repo call "Joe Working on Image 1". His branch has Image 1, which he wants to work on, and 10,000 other images that he has no interest in.

Jane might create a branch of the same repo called "Jane working on Image 987". Her branch has Image 987, which she wants to work on, and 10,000 other images that she has no interest in.

This is fine as long as Joe and Jane aren't tempted to start editing some other images in their branch. But if they did, we lose the conceptual model of each image being edited as an independent entity, and edited in isolation from the other images.

So if Joe edited Image 2 in the branch where he should have been editing only Image 1, and merged those changes back into the repo, we now the explicit revision history of Image 2 being edited along side Image 1. But Image 1 and 2 should be completely independent. There should be no notion of Image 2 as it was edited alongside Image 1.

So this is the crux of the question. Does GIT support the notion of the files it controls as isolated entities whose revisions don't correlate to any other file? Or can this only be achieved with individual git repos for every file?

UPDATE 2

It looks like a [submodule](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial) might be a replacement for having thousands of GIT repos.

Comment: GitHub’s Gists work the way that *every* Gist is its own repository. And most of the Gists contain only a single file, so yeah it’s definitely working well for single files.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't seen Gists before.

Comment: That sounds like a perfect task for [RCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System)...

Comment: he does say that they are interested in branching/merging, which won't work with RCS.

Comment: What you describe sounds much like [ClearCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_ClearCase)...

Comment: So, you are explicitly asking how to do this with git, but I for one felt it was novel and interesting to look at what else is out there: SVN has xdelta; ClearCase or Perforce might fit; there is a product category "digital asset management" including open source; I remembered that commons.wikimedia.org runs on MediaWiki. I'm sure there are additional possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, git can be used for many single-file repos, although it's (as you point out) more made for managing a set of files.

To manage thousands of single-file repositories, the [Gitslave tool](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/) might help. This tool allows to create a bunch of repos, and manage them all in one. Once you have your repos, you can of course work with each one independantly, but Gitslave makes it easy to make group operations on them like push/pull or commit.

This is IMHO a better solution as having many git submodules, as submodules can be tricky to work with.

From the home page:

> Gitslave creates a group of related repositories—a superproject repository and a number of slave repositories—all of which are concurrently developed on and on which all git operations should normally operate; so when you branch, each repository in the project is branched in turn. Similarly when you commit, push, pull, merge, tag, checkout, status, log, etc; each git command will run on the superproject and all slave repositories in turn.

[...]

> Gitslave does not take over your repository. You may continue to use
>   legacy git commands both inside of a gits cloned repository and
>   outside in a privately git-cloned repository.

Comment: @Phyxx wow, wasn't expecting winning the bounty! It will be great to know how you managed it in practice

Answer (score 3):

I don't really see the problem. I think you see a repository as a way of versioning your code (files in this case). Though that is right, the idea can lead you to an error because it doesn't mean that you commit always version in the form X.Y

What I mean is that you can see a repo as a timeline in which you have different states of the content of a folder. It doesn't matter whether the files are related to each other or not.

With git you can always get an old version of a single file, you don't need to go back to a complete state of the repo.

So, there is no difference at all, in your case, between one repo with several independent files and several repos with one file each. Actually there is a big difference, the first option is afordable and the second is imposible to handle.

Actually a normal project has files that are totally independent but they all belongs to the same repo.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I still don't see the problem. When I'm working in my project I modify sometimes one file but I have to create a complete branch anyway. So both cases are actually the same. The issue with modifying Picture B when your branch should be only for picture A can be solved with a good work discipline. Each member should work in the way he has to. Creating a submodule for each picture sounds similar to a new repository for each picture, I wouldn't do it. It doesn't seem to be developed for that; read first parragraph of http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: I agree that good work discipline would go a long way, but a lack of discipline (or a lack of associated resources like training and managerial oversight) has been identified as one of the biggest risks to our project. The problem with cloning is that it makes it far to easy to put off or completely ignore the step where you merge the changes back in. And when a clone contains multiple edited files, not just the one that should have been edited, the merging process becomes even more daunting, and therefore easier to ignore. It's a vicious circle.

Comment: If that is a big risk then the solution may be a bit risky :) What if you introducing Code Reviewing in your process? I explain: you commit your changes, push them to github and ask for PullRequest, then other member of the team has to review that the changes are correct and only then the owner of the branch can merge it

Comment: The process of submitting a pull request unfortunately falls prey to the same lack of training and managerial oversight i.e. it is another step that is likely not to be done. I think it is becoming clear that git is designed for monolithic code bases, and is not really suited to a lot of independent projects that are only related at a high conceptual level.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. I believe that for your goal you need something different. If you find it I would appreciate if you tell us

Answer (score 2):

Git has no problems with you creating a repository for a single file.

If you don't want to create a repository per file and don't require to see all those files in their directory at the same time, you could just start with an empty repository and create a branch for each of those files. If you don't do any merges between these independent branches, they will stay independent. You will still be able to create new branches off of a specific file`s branch and merge changes back.

Comment: In our case that would mean creating tens of thousands of git repos. Could anyone comment on the practicality of this?

Comment: In this case some shell scripting skills, if you have some, might be a great help, since I don't see (but haven't searched) any tool that fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I use CVS where each file is independent of all the others in the repository.

As a bonus, this lets you execute "cvs update" on some files, while leaving others alone.

This comes in handy where I may have modified files on the local workspace, and also checked in changes from another workspace.  I often want to sync up with the files that have changed in the repository only, while not bothering to deal with files that might need to be merged.

This led to a script I call cvs-update-safe which quickly and painlessly updates any files that are safe to update, while leaving other files alone to be dealt with manually later.

I'm not a huge fan of CVS for anything of any complexity (I much prefer git), but it has the advantages of being ubiquitous, and allowing me the option of updating only parts of a repository.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# $Id: cvs-update-safe,v 1.1 2007-11-02 19:47:02 falk Exp $

usage = """Like cvs update, but only updates files which will update cleanly.

Usage:  cvs-update-safe [files...]
"""

import sys
import os
import string
import commands

def main():
  cmd = 'cvs -n update ' + string.join(sys.argv[1:], ' ')
  output = commands.getoutput(cmd).split('\n')
  olist = []
  for line in output:
    line = line.split()
    if line[0] is 'U' and len(line) is 2:
      olist.append(line[1])
  if olist:
    cmd = 'cvs update ' + string.join(olist, ' ')
    os.system(cmd)
  else:
    print 'Nothing to update'



if __name__ == "__main__":
  sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single repo and use git hooks to enforce a granularity of one.

A client side pre-commit hook would ensure that a commit had changes to a single file, and optionally a prepare-commit-msg hook would automatically prefix the commit message with the name of the file.

A server side pre-receive hook could enforce the above.

You would still have the signal-noise problem of eventually having a large number of independent branches.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you started this discussion with wrong question.

The paragraph:

> Each of these files [...] and access the files from
>   other projects that use GIT.

(esspecially: *access the files from other projects that use GIT*)
suggests, that all you want is collection of repositories, accessed from other project.

I think, that the best solution is to use submodules.

Set a new repository for each of your "files". I will call them "one-file-repo".

In the project that uses "one-file-repo" repositories define submodules.

The fact, that your "one-file-repo" repositories contain a single file is not important.

The work within "one-file-repo" is isolated, but not necessarily restricted to a single file.

Answer (score 0):

With a single repository you can choose to only commit one file at a time, giving each file a different commit message. But when you clone the repo, you're still going to end up downloading the whole repository. Git is a [distributed version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) system, and this is a side effect of that.

You could give each file its own git repository and import them into other git repositories using submodule. I can see that being somewhat of a pain to manage, but the pros of using a dvcs is you always have the history of your repository on your computer.

Another thing to consider is you might be using the wrong tool for the job. SVN is a centralized version control system, and it allows you to check out single files (sparse checkout) instead of cloning the entire repository. You can use tools like git-svn to bridge to your existing Git repositories.

Either way it's not a fun process. Having a separate git repo per file might be the least complicated.